# How to compare more than 2 groups on the group rate?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, poisson-regression, controlling-for-a-variable

I need to compare more than 2 organizations on the number of events each has, controlling for the number of buildings. The number of events per organization is small (0 - 6) and the number of buildings per organization is large (600 - 6000). This is not a contingency table because multiple events could occur in a single building. I expect Events to be Poisson distributed, with log(buildings) as the offset, but I don't think Poison regression will work because I want to compare groups, but each group has only 1 rate.

Here is some mock data:

| Organization | Events | Buildings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2000 |
| 2 | 1 | 3000 |
| 3 | 0 | 4000 |
| 4 | 4 | 6000 |
| 5 | 1 | 600 |
| 6 | 6 | 3000 |

Alternatively, I could reframe the question to be whether group 6 differs from the other groups. Then I would need to use the other 5 groups to create a confidence interval and see if group 6 falls outside the interval. I know how to get a CI for the mean of the other 5 groups, but I need the CI for a single score. I also know how to get a CI for just the event counts, without taking the buildings into account. I haven't been able to figure out how to turn 5 rates (or counts with offsets) into a distribution of individual scores.

I'm most familiar with frequentist methods and I work mainly in Python and SPSS. I'll also do manual calculations in a spreadsheet if needed, or I'm willing to code a permutation test if I can get my head around how to do it. Any help is appreciated!

Clarification requested by @dipetkov:

- The original question asks about *more than 2 organizations*
- I changed the table header "Group" to "Organization" to be consistent with the question
- The number of buildings are all multiples of 100 because I was lazy when I made the mock data. The general scale of the mock data is consistent with the real data, but in the real data the numbers of buildings are not multiples of 100.
- Organization 6 noticed that they had high numbers and made policy changes in response. That led to a more general question about whether Organization 6 is different from the other organizations. So, in a sense, what makes Organization 6 special is that it has a high number of events. I am aware that looking at the group with the most extreme score *because it has the most extreme score* will inflate Type I error rate. I accept that and will deal with that, but I need some starting point from which to be able to say something about where Organization 6 falls on the distribution of what's expected.

Comment: Please clarify the problem. For example: Your question mentions 2 organizations but the sample data doesn't refer to organizations and instead has a *group* column with at least 6 groups. Why is the numbers of buildings exact multiples of 100? What's special about group 6?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @dipetkov I edited the post to clarify the points you asked about. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: As you say, since you have only one observation from from organization 6, you can't estimate its rate. But you can estimate a common rate for the other five organization. And then maybe look at something like the probability of 6 events in 3000 buildings at that rate? Perhaps better: the posterior probability of 6 events in 3000 buildings given data from organizations 1 to 5. You'd need to make lots of assumptions....

Comment: @dipetkov Yes! That's what I need to do! I don't know how to estimate the distribution of rates from the other 5 organizations. I could specify the appropriate Poisson distribution if I weren't accounting for the number of buildings. Or, if the rates were normally distributed, I could handle that. I seem to have a distribution that is shaped much like a Poisson distribution, but it is rates, not counts. I don't know how to use the sample to specify the range within which 95% of organizations are expected to fall.